# Return value from inner callback function; call must block

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's take a look at this:

```
protected getSettingByKey(key: string) : string {

    let ret = null;

    let api : BrowserAPI = Browser.getCurrentBrowserAPI();

    let setting = api.readSetting(this.getUUID() + "." + key, "true", (value:string) => {
        ret = key;
    });

    while (true) {
        if (ret != null) return ret;
        console.log("KEY IS NULL, SKIPPIN");
    }

}
```

This is a function that reads the browsers native data storage for settings and ***MUST*** block until the function `readSetting()` returns something.

I tried the above approach but it ends up being a dead loop.

I repeat, the function ***MUST***, by all means ***BLOCK***, it must ***NOT*** have any callback.

How to realize that?

I know this is an anti-pattern but that's the way it has to be.

Comment: You MUST not try to use blocking functions. I repeat, you can NEVER, by any means, BLOCK on an asynchronous functions.

Comment: Your only choice is to rewrite `api.readSetting` to make it synchronous, such as changing the XMLHttpRequest call to be `async: false`. But as others have mentioned, you probably don't want to do that. Why do you think you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `api.readSetting` is asynchronous, you **cannot** do that.

From the multiple statements in the question that it must block and must not use a callback, I assume you're familiar with the fact that the solution here is *not* to block and to use a callback (directly, or via promises), [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).

But without doing that, if you're calling an async function, you **cannot** make your function synchronous. You cannot synchronously wait for an asynchronous process to complete in browser-based JavaScript.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I assumed there is some way to screw over the runtime (like you do 90% of the time in Web Development; `How can I trick the browser to do *this*?`) but I assume there is no way. Oh well.

Comment: @Gala: There isn't, no. *(I have to say that that characterization doesn't match my experience of web development.)*